# How to use the Anaconda environment on blender?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, blender, environment

I'm having problems to use some modes like numpy and pandas on blender, apparently the blender's python do not allow us to install packages using pip; so I thought that I could resolve this issue changing its environment to the Anaconda or something like that. I looked for solutions, but all I founded worked on windows but I use ubuntu. If someone can help me, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I proceed:

### Deactivate current python used by Blender

→ Go to your Blender files (for example: `cd /usr/share/blender/3.0/`)

→ Deactivate the current python version: `mv python _python`

### Create a new anaconda environment

**Warning**

As mentioned [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_tips_and_tricks.html#bundled-python-extensions), the python version ([major and minor](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-check-python-version/)) must match the one that Blender comes with. For Blender 3.0, python 3.9 is ok.

→ Enter : `conda create --name=blender python=3.9`

→ When the installation is finished, enter: `conda activate blender`

### Link the Anaconda environment to Blender

→ If you have installed Anaconda with the default parameters, your conda env’ should be installed here: `~/anaconda3/envs/blender/`

→ So, enter: `sudo ln -s ~/anaconda3/envs/blender/ python`

This creates a junction between the python folder in the Blender files and the folder in the Anaconda environments files.

### Install new python packages

In a terminal, run: `pip (or conda) install [package_name]` under the blender anaconda environment (use: `conda activate blender` to switch environment)

I have rewritten these instructions from another tutorial I have written [here](https://quantum-creative-group.gitlab.io/quantum_nodes_manual/getting_started/installation_instructions/linux.html#anaconda-env-and-blender-linux)
The tutorial is for another tool, but I needed to setup quite the same environment as what you want, I guess.

Comment: This procedure only works on non-Windows systems unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

after struggling with this several times, and coming across it right now, I figured I'd share my solution.

long story short: just install things into the default blender environment or install `bpy` into an anaconda environment

On linux you may be able to follow Failxxx's answer, or using `mklink` in Windows maybe the same (I couldn't get it to work, got weird "compiler" errors when trying to import `bpy` in blender).

You can also check here for various workarounds:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_tips_and_tricks.html

In the end, I've had success building `bpy` as a module inside of an anaconda environment (follow tutorial in link), or installing whatever packages I want inside of my Blender python environment.

To do this.. find out where your Blender's python.exe is stored.. mine is here:

`C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\python\bin`

then, open a cmd as admin (admin was extremely crucial for my machine?) in this directory and do something like:

`python -m pip install pandas`

this will install the package into your Blender python environment. Sometimes I had to uninstall and reinstall with admin incase anything had been installed to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming - Python or Blender folders`.

if it's only a handful of packages, this is the best way in my opinion. Just know that this permanently alters the python environment that shipped with Blender.

Proof :) :

[image: proof]